# WPF. ObservableCollection<string> ListBox binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Как забайндить ListBox'у коллекцию строк? Со своим типом вопросов нет. А вот что делать с обычной строкой? Сделал как тут [enSO: MVVM-How to Binding ObservableCollection of Strings into ListBox WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24175983/5275890)
но не помогло

```
ObservableCollection<string> searchResultList

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding searchModel.searchResultList}">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Binding должен быть к свойствам(get; set;), в вашем случае это поле, так не работает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В оригинальном ответе на enSO речь идёт о замене части шаблона элемента списка, а не добавлении `TextBlock` в коллекцию `ListBox`, как сделали вы. В вашем случае будет достаточно просто:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding searchModel.searchResultList}" />
```

Со строчками `ListBox` умеет работать без переопределения шаблона элемента.

Эквивалентной записью было бы:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding searchModel.searchResultList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Как верно замечают в комментарии, `searchResultList` должен быть публичным свойством, а не приватным полем.

Comment: Эквивалентный скорее будет не `TextBlock`, а `ContentPresenter`. Но эффект по сути тот же...

Comment: @Андрей, `ListBox` оборачивает всё, что не есть `ListBoxItem`, в `ListBoxItem`. Поскольку `ListBoxItem` - `ContentControl`, в визуальном дереве `ContentPresenter` естественно будет, но он не сам показывает строчки, он абсолютно аналогично приведённому коду отображает её при помощи `TextBlock`. [Пруф в статическом конструкторе `ContentPresenter`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ContentPresenter.cs,63). Задавая `ItemTemplate` ручками мы по сути подменяем шаблон из кода по ссылке на свой. И там, и там используется `TextBlock`.

Comment: @Андрей, разница может быть только в задании свойств `TextBlock`. Может быть там есть некоторое количество не дефолтных значений для каких-то свойств.

Answer (score 3):

Не работает потому что:

```
ObservableCollection<string> searchResultList
```

во-первых поле, а не свойство(Binding работает только со свойствами). Во-вторых оно приватное, должно быть `public`

```
public ObservableCollection<string> searchResultList { get; set; }
```

xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding searchResultList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```